# Javascript Disable button when a specific option is selected

Tags: javascript

I have a code here but the code for disabling the button is not working.

Button with link

```
   <button id="link-button">
    <a id="link-web" href="" style="text-decoration:none">GO TO LINK</a>
   </button>
```

Select Option

```
<select id="website" onchange='selecWeb(this)'>
  <option>Search Engine</option>
  <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="https://bing.com">Bing</option>
 </select>
```

JS Code

```
function selecWeb(a){
    var val = a.value;

    if(a.options[a.selectedIndex].text== "Search Engine")
    {
        $('#link-button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#link-button').prop('disabled', false);
        document.getElementById('link-web').href = val;
    }
}
```

Why prop`('disabled', true)` is not working?
Is there another way?

Comment: Try the following : document.getElementById('btn1').disabled = true;

Comment: You are adding a tag inside the button. the button is getting disabled but the click event is triggered on the <a> tag, not the button. So best way is to add click event to the button and remove the a tag

Answer (score 1):

Use JS [disabled](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp) attribute :

```
document.getElementById("id").disabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have nested an `a` tag inside a `button` tag, which is not allowed by HTML5. A button can not contain interactive content. JSFiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/ykv695en/

```js
function selecWeb(a){
    var val = a.value;

    if(val == "SearchEngine")
    {
        $('#link-button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#link-button').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#link-button').off();
       $('#link-button').click(function(){
        location.href = val;
       });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="link-button">
    GO TO LINK
   </button>
   <select id="website" onchange='selecWeb(this)'>
  <option value="SearchEngine">Search Engine</option>
  <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="https://bing.com">Bing</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: this will bind multiple click events to the button

Comment: @suhailc Thanks for telling me. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @hev1 is it better to make a click function outside and get the value of selection inside the function and proceed to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Using `change` add a disabled class that will disable the `href` value of the `a` tag based on the selects new value.

```js
$('#website').change(function(event) {
  if($(this).val() === 'Search Engine') {
    $('#link-button a').addClass('is-disabled');
  } else {
    $('#link-button a').removeClass('is-disabled');
    $('#link-button a').attr('href', $(this).val());
  }
});
```

```css
a.is-disabled {
  color: currentColor;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="link-button">
  <a id="link-web" class="is-disabled" href="" style="text-decoration:none">GO TO LINK</a>
</button>

<select id="website">
  <option>Search Engine</option>
  <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
  <option value="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
  <option value="https://bing.com">Bing</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

here are two things.
 first that : anchor tag is inside a button element
 second: anchor tag doesn't have disabled property.

so your code be something like this

```
 <button id="link-button">GO TO LINK</button>
 <select id="website" onchange='selecWeb(this)'>
            <option>Search Engine</option>
            <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
            <option value="https://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
            <option value="https://bing.com">Bing</option>
  </select>
<script>
function selecWeb(a) {
        var val = a.value;

        if (a.options[a.selectedIndex].text == "Search Engine") {
            $('#link-button').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#link-button').prop('disabled', false);
            document.getElementById('link-web').href = val;
        }
    }
 </script>
```